# Why I'm getting an error when looking for an index using window variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, window

This is very strange, I'm trying to use a variable which I define as is:

```
window.params['variable'] = { ... };
```

In the function I'm using I have this:

```
function q()
{
 ...
 // for example
 return new Chart( canvas, window.params['variable'] );
 ...
}
```

When I execute this I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'variable' of undefined`

But, incredible (for me), when I define params as:

```
window.params = { ... }
```

The error disappear, and the function runs fine! why?

(Obviusly I replace the `window.params['variable']` by `window.params` first, but I believe that this is equivalent)

Thanks.

Comment: can you expand the first assignement `window.params['variable'] = { ... };
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `params` first before adding properties to `params`. 
So the right way to do it is

```
window.params = {};
window.params['variable'] = { };
```

or

```
window.params = {
  'variable' : {}
};
```

and then

```
function q(){
 ...
 // for example
 return new Chart( canvas, window.params['variable'] );
 ...
}
```

You will get more information about this here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Look at here https://jsfiddle.net/sLww6c4u/, in the line 114 you can see the main problem I'm having with this, independent of usage of window variable, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please replace chartParams['mychart'] by paramsWork and it will work, the params in same places are the same structure, why doesn't work wit chartParams['mychart'] that is what I need? thanks.

Comment: Here `chartsParams` is an array. So `chartParams['mychart'] ` is not valid. Instead use `chartParams[0]['mychart']`

Comment: Hi @Diode , thanks by your help, now I write to you to put on your hands a new challenge :) This is the main trouble related to this question: please look at this new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189944/how-to-solve-a-chart-js-2-0-issue-with-mouseover-and-several-updates maybe you can help me. Thanks!